# Missing Android platform(s) detected

Tags: android, sdk

After trying to gradle sync... it fails and says in the messages dialog box

```
Missing Android platform(s) detected: 'android-26' Install missing platform(s) 
and sync project
```

when im clicking `Install missing platform(s) and sync project` a progress bar window pops up which says `Downloading` and when reaching about half way it just closes and nothing happens
ive installed api 26 from the settings and tried uninstall and install again.

Comment: try restart Android Studio.

Comment: @AnujJindal still no change

Comment: Uninstall android-26 platform from your sdk and redownload it.

Comment: Remove it manually or use a platform you have already downloaded and use it for your project

Comment: @Lucifer ive done that too still no change

Comment: @hilaedri are you using firewalls ?

Comment: @Lucifer only windows's firewall

Comment: I think your firewall might be blocking 'SDK update sites'

Comment: i disabled the firewall and nothing

Comment: Ive figured this out. really appreciate your help @Lucifer

Comment: invalid cashes and restart android studio works for me

Comment: If another way not work. Try my way. See the link below:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429796/7208299)

Answer (score 6):

If you have the message:

> Missing Android platform (s) detected

And you see that the SDK is installed. Here is the procedure to solve your problem.

Select menu "**File" -> "Project Structure ..."** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), select "**SDK Location**" and click on button "**...**" to edit "**Android SDK Location**" :

[image: Button to edit Android SDK Location]

In the **dialog box**, "**select the directory where is installed the SDK**" (For me: /home/mathieu/Android/Sdk).

**Click on next until the end of the procedure.**

Your project should now recompile with the SDK. I hope I've helped you!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Problem Starts Here: ["Install missing platform(s) and sync project" (link) doesn't work & gradle sync failed]

you can solved it by changing the target version from 26 to any above version. i have not tried any below version.
first install the higher version let suppose it is 27. which is android 8.1 Oreo.
[image: how to install android 8.1 Oreo v27]

Now open the build.gradle from your project and

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.2.0'
```

change these line from 26 to 27

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.3.0'
```

and also change the compileSdkVersion 26 to 27 and targetSDKVersion to 27

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kashif.silenceinmasjid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

than synchronized

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved when I realized that my Android SDK was placed in **C:/User/Admin** while I was logged in Windows by a different account which needed permissions to access **C:/User/Admin** directory. I changed my user account to **Admin** and it worked fine on it. If you want to use it on the same account however, you should change permissions from the Admin account to let other users access it.

Answer (score 0):

I install the NDK.and config the ndk path [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found by watching this video.

Link - [Find the missed Image Asset in Android studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TQoSMBhE6k)

Steps to be taken(Assuming You are working on Android, but It worked for me working on flutter as well)

1. Open the PARENT android project in a new Android Studio Window. [Open the Android project in a new Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhqvK.png)
2. [Search for the Android root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoZTP.png). Let the Gradle Sync run for some time
3. Try again, right clicking the res folder. This time it will come up.

Core Problem - It is an Issue with the Gradle sync not done properly, but with the above approach we forced Android Studio to resync it.